# How to terminate outgoing CSD call?

Tags: gsm, at-command

I have a gsm modem called **iRZ**. I use it for CSD call(getting meterage from meter). I call to meter like this: ATDpho0ne_number
Then I exchange data. 
And finally I need to terminate this call, but how?

I tried: "+++" next "ATH", and "ATH0". But it doesn't work...
Help, please...

Comment: I'm sorry, I've not found any standard way to do what you ask. I know how to do it in Telit modules, but it is a custom command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not specify the exact modem type so I tell you two options.

Option 1:

The +++ character sequence must be preceded and
followed by a pause of at least 1000 ms. The +++ characters must be entered in quick succession, all within 1000 ms.

Option 2:

You have to set up a "code word" by ATM Control utility and that code word will switch back the modem to AT mode and then you can issue the ATH command.